# Is there alternative of the "<=>" operator from Perl in C/Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, perl, compare

I'm implementing some custom NSArray sort selectors and I was wondering whether there's anything like the <=> operator in C/Objective-C?

I have this:

```
if (self.count == otherObject.count) return 0;
return (self.count > otherObject.count)? 1 : -1;
```

and would love to have (as in Perl)

```
return self.count <=> otherObject.count;
```

Comment: Hey Dani, lotta anger there :))) I am just asking if there is such operator - it's no drama if there isn't

Comment: @Dani: There's no reason a compiled language couldn't, or shouldn't, have an operator like `<=>`.  It's a perfectly reasonable question.  The answer just happens to be no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe the `compare:` method is what you are looking for? `NSString`, `NSNumber` etc implement it. All compare-like methods in Cocoa returns a NSComparisonResult:

```
enum {
   NSOrderedAscending = -1,
   NSOrderedSame,
   NSOrderedDescending
};
typedef NSInteger NSComparisonResult;
```

So you can use the returned integer value directly. Assuming that `count` in your question is a `NSNumber` you can do:

```
return [self.count compare:otherObject.count];
```

If your case is limited to numbers and you want to use just an operator you can probably use good old minus. But be aware of integer overflow!:

```
return self.count - otherObject.count;
```

Comment: Mattias, this is exactly what I was looking for :) All this time I somehow assumed the "compare:" should return {-1,0,+1} and didn't know it could be any positive or negative integer ... thus ... your golden "return self.count - otherObject.count" line is precisely what I was looking for

Comment: Glad i could help! but be aware when using minus to not cause a integer overflow if the compared numbers could be very far apart. Consider the case `return INT_MIN - INT_MAX`. In your case i guess `count` is a `NSUInteger` and `NSComparisonResult` is `NSInteger` so things probably go wrong if e.g. `self.count` is 0 and `otherObject.count` is more than `INT_MAX`. Just a heads up! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's called the [Spaceship Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceship_operator) and it originated in Perl; besides Perl, only Ruby and Groovy have it.

Answer (score 0):

Not in C, and probably not in Objective-C.

You could write a function easily enough, though it would be specific to a particular operand type:

```
int compare(int x, int y) {
    return x < y ? -1 : (x > y);
}
```

Or you could write a macro, which could be applied to any type with `<`, `==`, and `>` operators, but it would sometimes evaluate its arguments more than once:

```
#define COMPARE(x, y) ((x) < (y) ? -1 : ((x) > (y)))
```

(Note that both versions depend on the `>` operator yielding 0 for false, 1 for true.)

Comment: yeah both options are valid, but I was just looking how to simplify a sorting selector (as mentioned in the question) so Mattias's answer was really spot on